# PHP for each loop error

Tags: php

I have a loop to go through an array and each `checkbox` that is selected I want to put the value (also brought in dynamically) into my `QuestionSelected` table. I get this error `"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"` and I cannot get the results into my table. Here is the code I am trying:

```
//Declare the QuestionID as a array
$QuestionID = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="QuestionSelection"><input id="chkQuestion" type="checkbox" value=" '.$row['QuestionID'].'" name="question_'.$row['QuestionID'].'">' .$row['Question']. '</p></div><br/><br/>';

//Assign the QuestionID from the table to the var
$QuestionID[] = $row['QuestionID'];

}


if($_POST['submitted']) { 


$ids_list = '';

foreach($_POST["QuestionID"] as $id)
{
$ids_list .= (strlen($ids_list) > 0 ? ',' : '').mysql_real_escape_string($id);
}

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (`QuestionID`) VALUES (".$ids_list.")";

}//End of IF 'submitted
```

Comment: `$_POST["QuestionID"]` isn't an array.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: input name should be QuestionID[]

Comment: If I do a print_r(QuestionID) it returns 3 results so it looks as though its populating correctly? Wouldn't this be the right way to see?

Comment: do print_r($_POST['QuestionID']); as this is what you are foreach-ing

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysql_real_escape_string` ... **which extension are you actually using?** Please use prepared statements if you want to protect yourself from SQL injection. If you don't, at least use the same extension when trying to do so manually.

Comment: @rdlowrey you are saying use mysqli_real_escape_string correct? I want to make sure I am following what everyone is using

Comment: Well, I'm really saying you shouldn't use the manual escaping functions from either `mysqli` or `mysql` ... you should use the prepared statement functionality packaged with `mysqli` or PDO.

Comment: @WaygoodI just did print_r($QuestionID); and got the result: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) before I try this foreach loop. So my array values are in $QuestionID based on my understanding. So my issue is with the foreach and something I have done there. I just can't figure out what. Sorry if I'm missing something in your explaination

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your form, you are not using an array, but building the name values like:

```
name="question_'.$row['QuestionID'].'"
```

So `$_POST["QuestionID"]` does not exist and is not an array.

You can change your name building to:

```
name="QuestionID[]"
```

So that it is an array and you can even use the actual id as a key:

```
name="QuestionID[' . $row['QuestionID'] . ']"
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that my attempt is building name values and value values both (as ridiculous as that sounds) I wanted each checkbox to have a new name and then the value be my questionID from my table

Comment: I just did print_r($QuestionID); and got the result:  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) before I try this foreach loop. So my array values are in $QuestionID based on my understanding.  So my issue is with the foreach and something I have done there. I just can't figure out what. Sorry if I'm missing something in your explaination

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the issue and works:

```
$ids_list = '';

foreach($_POST["QuestionID"] as $key=>$value) {
{
$ids_list .= (strlen($ids_list) > 0 ? ',' : '').mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_QuestionSelected (`QuestionID`) VALUES (".$ids_list.")";

//Run the query 
$run2 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$sql2);


}
```